# Ratchet send doesn't work with sleep function

Tags: php, sleep, ratchet

Ratchet send doesn't work with the `sleep` function, how can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 180)
{
    foreach ($this->clients as $client)
    {

       $client->send($res->asXML()."\0");
    }
    sleep(2);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Non. Blocking. Event. Loop. How can you fix it? Don't call `sleep()`.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a good idea to use sleep() with ratchet.  Instead it would be best to take advantage of its existing event loop.

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but here is a basic example.  I am willing to bet that you will need to re-work your code to accommodate this different technique.

```
//Start the server
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new WsServer($session),
    $port,
    $addr
);

//Attach the loop
$server->loop->addPeriodicTimer(2, function () {
    $client->send($res->asXML()."\0");
});
```

Sources:

1. https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ratchet-php/MsTqELDoBb0/lQ_J8aR2eUcJ